# Zoomline:zone-evergreen.js:659 Unhandled Promise rejection: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 6 failed. in Angular 11

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, fusioncharts, angular11

I am using zoomline fusion charts with Ionic and angular and after I login on the Home screen I am loading fusion charts with data but it is not loading properly it shows and always shows **loading charts Please wait**

I have attached the Error Image
Can Anyone help me fix this Issue please!

[How my Zoomline FusionChart look on the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZbo5.png)

[This is the error I am getting in the chrome dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMnHw.png)

Comment: Can you post if there's an error on the console or the Terminal?

Comment: @RafaeldeCastro Console error.

Answer (score 1):

You are haven't imported **fusioncharts.zoomline.js** hence the error is showing, please use the below import statements

```
// Import angular-fusioncharts
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';

// Import FusionCharts library and chart modules
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import * as Zoomline from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.zoomline';

import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';

// Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts,Zoomline,FusionTheme);
```

Please reload the app clearing the browser cache. It should render.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Images you shared it Seems to me that you are not handling the Fusion Charts's Call back properly, or your Fusion charts are not mounted on the right life-cycle hooks

From what I understand Fusion chart wants you to initialize its library on the Vue instance on the very top [basically mount it globally] then on the component you return your data source after you have filled the data source with chart data...

Unless you share some code it would be difficult to dive deep into the error

Comment: i used fusion charts in home page but when i first time login after redirect to home page then the fusion charts will show 'loading fusion charts please wait '  and after i refresh home page in browser the fusion charts will show with data. In this error occurs only zoomline type fusion charts.

Comment: You mean when you refresh the home page you are able to see the charts with data but not when you login for the first time..